# How to change datatype of primary key field in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, sqldatatypes

In mysql workbench, I created a new table and added a column `id`, and by default its datatype is set to `INT`, `PK` and `NN` boxes are  selected. When I tried to change the datatype of `id` column to `VARCHAR()`, it gave the following error:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: check if autoincrement is also set

Comment: no, autoincrement is not set

Comment: change it to varchar(10) I believe you are missing the width of varchar

Comment: why is it needed? what is the difference between varchar() and varchar(45)?

Comment: you need to specify the width for varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `varchar()` it to `varchar(10)` I believe you are missing the `width of varchar`

Answer (score 0):

varchar() is an empty statement, seeking the width of the "string" that you are setting. You have to input the amount of characters to accept. (Ex: varchar(10) or varchar(45)).